# How can I filter weekends and holidays with iReport?

Tags: filter, ireport

I am trying to make a report with iReport so that it can show me the days that are holidays and weekends. To obtain the weekends I made a function that consults the table that has them and returns 1 or 0 to inform if it is a holiday or not. For the weekends I solved it with `this $V{date}.getDay() == 6 and $V{date}.getDay() == 0`, but I don't know how to get it to also be filtered with the `isholiday(date)`.

[image]

I hope that the report will paint me the days that are weekends and holidays.

Comment: That image is virtually unreadable. Please make sure you aren't presenting text as an image. See [ask] and take the [tour].